# Is　なにをうたがすきですか？　correct?

Tags: grammar

I want to ask

> What songs do you like?

Is

> なにをうたがすきですか？

the correct way of asking that?

I am trying to get better at building sentences but I have no way of knowing whether or not the sentence is correct, is it a problem if I continue to post questions like this here?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will answer your to the best of my ability but it was just a stone's throw from when I was at your level. Let's look at your sentence.

> なにをうたがすきですか?

"何{なに}を" is marked as the direct obect, but there is no verb to take it. 好{す}き is an adjective and です is the copula, so you need to rephrase your sentence.

どんな is OK since it means "what kind (of)..." so an acceptable sentence such as

> どんな歌{うた}が好きですか?

or

> なんの歌が好きですか ?

would suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. What's the difference between 何の and どんな ?

Comment: どんな歌 is "what kind of songs" and なんの歌 is "what songs", so in your sentence, there is not too much too much difference between the two

Answer (score 5):

[何]{なん}の[歌]{うた}が[好]{す}きですか? and どんな[歌]{うた}が[好]{す}きですか? are correct.

Comment: How do you read these kanji, 歌 and 好?

Comment: 歌 read うた and 好き read すき.